# Как сравнивать аналогичные строки?

Tags: java, python, c++, строки, equals

Допустим у меня есть приложение, которое в зависимости от входной строки выдаёт выходную. К примеру пишу `"Hello"` и в ответ получаю `"Hello"`.

Я хочу, чтобы приложение понимало и `"HeLLo"`, и с ошибками `"Helo"`.

Для начала я могу перевести строку в нижний регистр, но строка может состоять не только из одного слова. Я не хочу создавать список с фразами и тупо сравнивать.

Как это реализуют в больших проектах? (В чат-ботах например). Язык не важен, лучше объясните принцип. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: На ум приходят только регулярки

Comment: это не такая уж и простая проблема... Если вас интересуют уже готовые решения на эту тему, то это, пожалуй `elastic`

Comment: Вот пример регулярки для слова Hello "(H|h)(E|e)(LL|ll|Ll|lL|L|l)(O|o)"

Comment: Можно использовать метрики для сравнения полученной строки с эталонной, например, расстояние Левенштейна.

Comment: Я когда-то делал такой проект. Могу порыться и выложить на гитхаб. Там был смысл в том, что фразы парсились на слова и каждое слово искалось в словаре (большой файл правильных слов). Если его там не было, то проверялись определенные правила, которые предполагали то или иное искажение слова (например, пропуск буквы, перестановка буков, замена итд), а потом выбирались наиболее подходящие замены... Как-то так

Comment: Думаю, для ваших задач отлично подойдёт [алгоритм Вагнера-Фишера](https://habr.com/ru/post/279585/), используемый для нечёткого поиска

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Регулярками все не опишеш. В "больших" проектах это делается "большими" программами. 
Коих много.

https://netpeak.net/ru/blog/luchshiye-programmy-dlya-ispravleniya-orfograficheskikh-oshibok-story/

Есть и он-лайн.

https://bugaga.net.ru/orfografija/

https://www.xn----7sbbiparddsgqdgdxrq.xn--p1ai/

Есть и сервисы с соответствующим АIP.

Известна и теория этого дела (не простая). При желании можно и ознакомиться

http://www.100byte.ru/stdntswrks/spellCh/spellCh.html

Comment: Спасибо большое!